# How to allow/disallow tenant to access API in multi tenant system based on subscription of plan

Tags: java, api, spring-boot, multi-tenant

I'm designing a multi-tenant system in which individual tenant registers in the system and selects the plan which enables them to access modules based on those plans.

Currently, Tenant uses the system from the website but REST APIs are also exposed so the tenant can call any API.

I want to restrict the tenant using such modules API for which they haven't subscribed yet.

REST APIs are developed in Spring boot, JAVA.

Could anyone have an idea how to implement it in the backend.

Comment: Idea 1: use an API manager. Idea 2: have metadata in the database and check it on api calls, and return an error when not applicable.

Answer (score 1):

On a highlevel,
 1. Mark Allowed subscription plans for individual REST API endpoints either through Annotation or config xmls.
 2. Resolve the Request User's subscription plan at the Authorization Filter level
 3. Have a generic access controller which matches request user's attributes against REST API attributes and allows based on the match

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll work on that and let you know the outcome.